# Click all buttons and skip one when I get error exception,then continue clicking all of them. After exception is executed, not all buttons are clicked

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, loops, selenium-webdriver

I present to you some executable, functionable and GUI code, created for study purposes only.

I have a problem with automatic clicks after except, precisely, after the exception `ElementClickInterceptedException`, I would like to continue the automatic clicks code in a While Loop, but always RESPECTING the set number of buttons to click (`limit`). The problem is that not all buttons set are clicked since I get the exception. Basically if I set 20 clicks with limit, the script seems to work fine until I get the exception. After the exception the script still continues to click on some buttons, but not on 20. I can't understand what the problem is. There can be various reasons. This is the part that is troubling me (below is the complete code):

```
limit = int(number_requests.get())

i = 1
x = 1
        
while i <= limit:
    i = i + 1
        
    try:
        #These are the staves of the button list, useful for scrolling down. Each staff is a button
        row = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"(//div[@data-visualcompletion='ignore-dynamic' and not (@role) and not (@class)])[{i}]")))
        #click on button
        add = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Add Friend']"))).click()
        
        #vertical scroll down 
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", row)
        time.sleep(delay)
        
        
        
    except ElementClickInterceptedException:
        print("This button could not be clicked")
        
        close_popup = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Ok']"))).click()
        
        while True:
            x = x + 2
            row_skip = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"(//div[@data-visualcompletion='ignore-dynamic' and not (@role) and not (@class)])[{x}]")))
            addd_skip = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Add Friend']"))).click()
            break
```

**NOTE:** you will be wondering what is the xpath in "row"?. Below, going down here, I explain what is the xpath in "row" and show the screenshot

**WHAT DOES MY CODE DO?** The code I am showing you almost everything works fine, but there is something wrong. It works like this:

1. Automatically click on each button (setting the delay and the number of buttons to click)
2. As you click on the buttons, the list of buttons scrolls down with the vertical scrollbar
3. When I get the `ElementClickInterceptedException` error, the popup closes automatically (click "ok" to close)
4. Return to the list of buttons and skip a button (1, one only)
5. I continue the While loop code (including `limit`), then I keep clicking on each button and if I get the ElementClickInterceptedException error it returns to point 3, 4 and 5.

My code works fine at first, then there are problems, although I don't understand which one exactly.

**WHAT DO I WANT TO GET?** The purpose of the code is to skip a button (1, only one) when I get an ElementClickInterceptedException and keep clicking on the other buttons after the RESPECT exception of the number set in limit. Why do I want to skip a button in the exception with the second While?

**PROBLEM:** If i set 20 buttons to click, they don't actually click 20 buttons, but they don't actually click, for example only 11 or 12 buttons. Also it seems that we have problems in the vertical scrollbar (even if my code looks correct) because the scrollbar drops down just a little, then stops, so it doesn't display any other buttons.

My idea is that the problem could be one of these: either there is a problem with the scroll bar scrolling (it scrolls down only a little, then stops), or "limit" is entered in the wrong place or in wrong way, or when I get the exception it creates a problem in the "try" code (I also tried with finally, but without solution), or I don't know what other problem it could be

**ATTENTION, VERY IMPORTANT: WHY SECOND LOOP WHILE IN THE EXCEPTION?** When the popup closes, the script will continue to click the buttons, but the last button it got to with the exception will **change its name from "Cancel Request" to "Add Friend"**. Consequently, the script will continue to click endlessly on the same button, because the popup will open, then the popup will close, then the button will change its name, it will be clicked and the popup will open again.

How can I solve? Code complete is:

```
import tkinter as tk                    
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep
import time
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
import os

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile

from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("...")
root.geometry('530x500')
root.configure(bg='white')

topbar = tk.Frame(root, bg='#3b589e', height=42, width = 660)
topbar.place(x=1, y=1)

secondbar = tk.Frame(root, bg='#f0f2f5', height=42, width = 660)
secondbar.place(x=1, y=40)

#GUI
label_email = Label(root, text="email", bg='#3b589e', foreground="white")
label_email.place(x=2, y=10)
email = tk.Entry(root)
email.place(x=50, y = 9)

label_password = Label(root, text="password", bg='#3b589e', foreground="white")
label_password.place(x=260, y = 10)
password = tk.Entry(root)
password.place(x=335, y = 9)

link_label = Label(root, text="Post Link", bg='#f0f2f5', foreground="black")
link_label.place(x=2, y = 52)
link = tk.Entry(root, width = 50)
link.place(x=97, y = 50)

link.insert(tk.END, "https://www.facebook.com/FranzKafkaAuthor/posts/4221775217885172")

number_requests_label = Label(root, text="How many requests to send?", bg='white', foreground="black")
number_requests_label.place(x=2, y = 110)
number_requests = tk.Entry(root)
number_requests.place(x=4, y = 130)
number_requests.insert(tk.END, "20")

time_label = Label(root, text="Seconds between requests?", bg='white', foreground="black")
time_label.place(x=2, y = 180)
time_requests = tk.Entry(root)
time_requests.place(x=4, y = 200)
time_requests.insert(tk.END, "1")

email.insert(tk.END, "example@example.it")
password.insert(tk.END, "example password")


def start_with_limits(): 
    # get the values from the textboxes and convert them to integers
    delay = int(time_requests.get())
    limit = int(number_requests.get())

    #Access Facebook
    profile_path = '/usr/bin/firefox/firefox'

    options=Options()
    options.set_preference('profile', profile_path)
    options.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 4)
    options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', '127.0.0.1')
    options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', 9050)
    options.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_remote_dns", False)

    service = Service('/home/xxxx/bin/geckodriver')
    driver = Firefox(service=service, options=options)
    driver.set_window_size(600, 990)
    driver.set_window_position(1, 1)
    driver.get("http://www.facebook.com")

    #Cookies before login
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[data-cookiebanner="accept_button"]'))).click()

    #Login
    username_box = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'email')
    username_box.send_keys(email.get())
    password_box = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'pass')
    password_box.send_keys(password.get())

    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/form/div[2]/button'))).click()

    # --OPTIONAL
    #Cookies before login (Sometimes it is required while sometimes not
    #WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[aria-label='Allow all cookies'] span span"))).click()


    #Open link
    driver.get(link.get())

    #Click on icon-like
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='j1lvzwm4']"))).click()
    time.sleep(1)

    #Click su ALL
    WebDriverWait(driver, 2000).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]'))).click()
    time.sleep(1)

    #Scroll down and press "Add friend" buttons
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
    i = 1
    x = 1
    
    while i <= limit:
        i = i + 1

        try:
            row = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"(//div[@data-visualcompletion='ignore-dynamic' and not (@role) and not (@class)])[{i}]")))
            add = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Add Friend']"))).click()
        
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", row)
            time.sleep(delay)



        except ElementClickInterceptedException:
            print("This button could not be clicked")

            close_popup = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Ok']"))).click()

            while True:
                x = x + 2
                row_skip = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"(//div[@data-visualcompletion='ignore-dynamic' and not (@role) and not (@class)])[{x}]")))
                addd_skip = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Add Friend']"))).click()
                break

begin = Button(root, text="Start", bg='#3b589e', foreground='white', width=7, command= start_with_limits)
begin.place(x=1, y=420)

root.mainloop()
```

**ADD INFORMATION:** "i" has the main purpose of not skipping any staff, so it must scroll and count each staff (all staves). While "x", compared to "i", must skip 1 button (1 only), but it must skip it 1 time, then skip 1 button only 1 time. Subsequently, after the exception has jumped a button with "x", then it returns to the first While that clicks on all the buttons (not jumping any) until a new exception is found.

**XPATH IN ROW?** With the xpath in "row", I am selecting every single row where there is a button. The names of the row are all called the same. To be precise, on your screen, you have to click on the blue like icon and then click on "All". I am selecting every single staff of that section. P.S: (do not notice that my browser uses another language, obviously I will do the tests with another browser from the English language)
[image]

**P.S: I would like to point out that my question is for personal and informational study purposes only. I am new to Python and am now learning Selenium. I don't want to use spam and don't really want to use the script in real cases. Respect for Facebook rules. As I said, my question is just a curiosity for reasons of personal study to understand the code of this curiosity of mine.**

Comment: why the `while true` if you `break` immediately afterwards?

Comment: do you maybe mean to increment `i` inside the while loop, instead of `x`? how does incrementing `x` skip a button, if `x` is way behind `i` (it isn't incremented until you hit an exception)? why are you using `x` at all?

Comment: @Esther the second while (while True: x = x + 2, etc etc) i only need one (1) time because I have to skip a button. Right after jumping a button, I would like to go back to the first While Loop respecting "limit". I don't know if I wrote this second While Loop wrong, but if you have ideas, please help me. Thanks

Comment: @Esther "i" is used to increase the first While loop, then to click all the buttons one after the other. Instead, "x" instead are used in the second While loop (the exception one) to skip a button (1), and then return to the first While loop where I add all the buttons one after the other.

Comment: did you read my comments? how does skipping work with x? x is 0 when you enter the first while loop. you want to increment i, not x. And the second while loop can just be code outside a loop, because you only run it once, not in a looop.

Comment: @Esther Yes I have read your comments and thank you. I am aware that the code I wrote may be wrong, but I don't understand exactly what your question is. Thanks

Comment: where you use x, what number is it supposed to be in relation to i? one more than the i you just clicked (which threw the exception)? and then the next button you want to click is one more than that? or is x supposed to be the same as the i that threw the exception?

Comment: in short: the problem is likely with `x`. If you think about why you are using it, remove the while loop and only use `i` to reference numbers, you will likely fix this. It is not a mysterious bug, your code has problems.

Comment: @Esther "x must not be the same as" i "." i "has the main purpose of not skipping any staff, so it must scroll and count each staff (all staves). While" x ", with respect to" i ", must skip 1 button (1 only), but must skip 1 time, then skip 1 button only 1 time. Then, after the exception has skipped a button, it returns to the first While that clicks on all buttons ( not skipping anyone) until a new exception is found. If you understand the problem, can you show me the solution in the code? If so, I will vote and accept your answer. Thanks

Comment: let's say that your code hits an exception at i=4, and x=0 (because it doesn't get updated). you hit the `except` block, and x gets incremented to 2. now you try to skip button number 2, which it already clicked, and then it goes back to the beginning of the while loop, increments i to 5, and tries to click button number 5 (the one it was supposed to skip). is that what is happening? Is x supposed to be 2 the first time it hits an exception, or is that a mistake?

Comment: to be clear: i doesn't "not skip" anything, it just keeps track of the next button to click. If you want to skip a button, just increment i by one, for example if you just clicked 4 and want to skip 5, just increment i to 6 and then it will never end up clicking 5. I can't run this right now, or else I would try to fix, but please do think about it yourself and try to test this and debug yourself. make sure i and x are holding the values you think they are.

Comment: @Esther I wrote the code with the idea of ​​always incrementing the same number for both "i" and "x". So "i" increments 1 to click on a button on each staff, and "x" increments 2 to skip a button. For this reason I entered row = wait.until (EC.visibility_of_element_located ((By.XPATH, f "(// div [@ data-visualcompletion = 'ignore-dynamic' and not (@role)) and not (@class)] )[{I}]"))) which are the rows of the list of buttons, useful for scrolling down. Each staff is a button. I don't understand why you talk about incrementai to 4, 5, or 6. Can you show me what you say with an answer please?

Comment: `i` doesn't increment, it just holds a number. `x` doesn't increment either, it also just holds a number. You can change the value referenced by `i` by doing `i+=1`, that just makes `i` hold a larger number. `i` and `x` hold `different` numbers, unless you are careful to make sure they hold the `same` number, and changing one has no effect on the other. please go back and learn basics of python variables.

Comment: try `print`ing `i` and `x` every time you loop, so you can see what is actually  happening.

Comment: @Esther I know the basics of variables. Be careful not to offend people please. We had a misunderstanding of ideas and so I asked you politely if you could show your idea with an answer. You continued to comment and we continued not to understand each other. If you want to help me with an answer I will be happy, otherwise thanks anyway. There is no reason to offend people. Thanks anyway

Comment: if you do know, then you aren't implementing that knowledge. what do you think `i+=1` does? where is the value being incremented? why are you using both `i` and `x`?

Comment: did you try printing `i` and `x` as you run the code, so you see what's happening?

Comment: @Esther "i" and "x" are two different types of increments for my needs. Otherwise in the exception, after closing the popup, the script will always click on the same button indefinitely and crash. This is why "i" and "x" are different

Comment: but they *aren't* two different kinds of increments, they are variables that hold numbers. that's all. if you do `i = i+1` instead of `x = x+2` and use `i` instead of `x` in the string, it should work.

Comment: @Esther I have to skip a button, for this I use +2, it means I don't want to move to the next button, but I want to skip one (1) and then move to the next button (so the second next button). if I use +1, it won't skip and just go to the next button without skipping the button that blocks the script

Comment: @Esther FOR FUTURE READERS (but also for you), the problem with my question is not what you discussed in the comments. The problem is another. The buttons all seem to click without problems, but when I go to count them only a few buttons have been clicked (not the ones set in limit) and the scrollbar drops down just a little, then stops

Comment: What exactly do `i` and `x` signify? They're being used in the XPATH, so they must relate to some page component?

Comment: @Abhinav Mathur They are used to scroll down the rows of the "row" buttons. Each button has the same xpath code, so I scroll through the buttons with "i" and "x". When I start the script the list of buttons scrolls down correctly, but then after a few seconds it stops.

Comment: What are you selecting with the xpath contained in `row`? Searching for that xpath only gives 1 result, see https://i.ibb.co/64nTKBv/image.png

Comment: @Jas_99 so each row has a unique value which is sequentially increasing?

Comment: @soundwave With the xpath in "row", I am selecting every single row where there is a button. The names of the row are all called the same. Look: https://ibb.co/PgCnY04 . To be precise, on your screen, you have to click on the blue like icon and then click on "All". I am selecting every single staff of that section. P.S: (do not notice that my browser uses another language, obviously I will do the tests with another browser from the English language)

Comment: @Abhinav Mathur Is simple. It just counts all the rows one after the other :) While when I get the exception, I no longer have to count all the rows one after the other, but I have to skip and ignore a row of buttons, just a 1 row, BUT I only have to skip it once on one occasion, then it ends the exception and I go back to counting all the rows again one after the other as at the beginning. Can you help me please? (this time help me for real). Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to send a given number of requests and skip bad requests in a overly complicated way. This is likely the simplest way to do it:

- check if an user has the “Add Friend” button

  - if yes, click the button

    - if the error box appears, close it, otherwise increment by 1 the number of sent requests
- if the desired number of requests were sent, stop, otherwise go to the next user

.

```
requests_to_send = 20
requests_sent = 0
requests_failed = 0
i = 0 # number of users checked
users = []

while requests_sent < requests_to_send:
    
    # if necessary, wait until new users are loaded
    while i >= len(users):
        users = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[aria-label=Reactions] div:nth-child(3) div[data-visualcompletion=ignore-dynamic]')
        time.sleep(.5)

    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: "center"});', users[i])
    button = users[i].find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[aria-label="Add Friend"]')
    
    if button:
        button[0].click()
        time.sleep(2)
        cant_send = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[aria-label=OK]')
        
        if cant_send:
            requests_failed += 1
            cant_send[0].click()
            # wait until popup is closed
            while driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[aria-label=OK]'):
                time.sleep(.5)
        else:
            requests_sent += 1
    
    i += 1
    print(f'users checked {i} - req. sent {requests_sent} - req. failed {requests_failed}', end='\r')
```

p.s. fanne buono uso!

Comment: There is something wrong with your code. When I can't click on a user's button and then the popup (error box) opens, then your code doesn't click on the "Ok" button, so it doesn't close. Consequently I get an error. Can you fix your code? Thanks

WebDriverError @ chrome: //remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm: 183:5
ElementClickInterceptedError @ chrome: //remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm: 282: 5
webdriverClickElement @ chrome://remote/content/marionette/interaction.js: 166: 11
interaction.clickElement@ chrome://remote/content/marionette/interaction.js: 125: 11

Comment: A curiosity: you wrote the code so that when the error box appears, close it, ok. But if it closes, then the code will infinitely click on the same button that previously caused the error box, because this button will change its name from "Cancel Request" to "Add Friend" right away when the error box is closed.

Comment: @Jas_99 The error box is closed correctly, moreover when it is closed the code will NOT infinitely click on the same button, but will go to the next user as you can see from this video that I have recorderd while the code above was running https://mega.nz/file/Mtp0mIDT#Xen51sm2zRZTruAZg3ZdhjVpzvB18yl00ofsRo0h6_w For example the error box appears for the user Ingrid Menzel, so it is closed and then goes to the next user. If you have errors try to increase `time.sleep(2)` to `time.sleep(5)` or more

Comment: I had to replace By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div [aria-label = OK]') with By.XPATH, "// span [text () = 'Ok']". Now works. There is a small problem, perhaps I expressed myself incorrectly in the question, but for example if I set 20 requests, I would like to click on 20 buttons in total (including those that I cannot click): in this way I would avoid spam. (continued in the following comment...)

Comment: (part 2 of comment) With your code (which is correct and you are a big one), to add 20 users you will click a lot of buttons: in this way facebook could block me. For example to add 20 users, I got this result: users checked 62 - req. sent 20 - req. failed 15. 62 button clicks are too many. Can you change your code please? I would like to click on 20 total buttons, not 20 friend requests. Then print how many users I have successfully added and how many have not been added. I'm sorry that maybe I didn't express myself well in the question. Hope you will be kind enough to help me. Thank you :)

Comment: @Jas_99 62 aren't the "add friend" buttons clicked, but the users for which the script checked if the button was available or not. Of these 62 users, only 35 (20+15) had the button, so the total number of clicked buttons is 35 not 62. If you want this total number to be equal to 20, then you have to replace `requests_sent < requests_to_send` with `(requests_sent+requests_failed) < requests_to_send`

Comment: So in the case of users checked 62 - req. sent 20 - req. failed 15, does that mean 35 button clicks were required to send 20 friend requests? Sorry, I hope you are kind enough to help me add a small and easy thing: how can I add a quick row of code to ignore the buttons where it says "Cancel Request"? I am referring to buttons that have already been clicked previously (user to whom a friend request has been successfully sent). So a little rows to NOT consider in the click count those buttons with written "Cancel Request" (clicked previously). Meanwhile, I voted for your answer. Thanks

Comment: @Jas_99 Yes 35 "Add friend" buttons were clicked, but 15 failed due to the error popup. The buttons "Cancel Request" are already ignored, actually all the buttons except for the "Add Friend" buttons are ignored. This is clear from the code `button = users[i].find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[aria-label="Add Friend"]')` you see that it contains 'Add Friend'? It means that it looks for the "add friend" button for the current user, and if it doesn't find it then it goes to the next user

Comment: I was testing your code, but got this error as the buttons were being pressed and the scrollbar scrolled down to the bottom. What does it mean? How can this be solved? I also tried to increase the seconds of the time, but it didn't help.  Error:     driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: "center"});', users[i])
IndexError: list index out of range. UPDATE:  Sometimes I get this error, and sometimes I don't get it

Comment: I also get this error (sometimes I get it and sometimes not). I use a screenshot because the error text is too long https://ibb.co/Zhhjxck . How can you fix this error and the one in the previous comment? The peculiarity is that I get these errors only a few times, such as when you run the script on the same link for the second time, so when there are already users added previously. But sometimes even the first time

Comment: I hope you will be able to solve these 2 errors (of the two previous mistakes) caused by your kind code. Don't worry, if the bounty expires then there are another 24 additional hours. Thanks

Comment: @Jas_99 both errors should be fixed now

Comment: Not sure, but now it seems to be working. I didn't understand the new changes you added. Can you change the bulleted list where you explain the code? I believe it works differently now. Can you explain in more detail? Can you tell me 3 things please? Can you explain me what it is for while i> = len (users) with users = driver ...? Can you explain to me why you have the driver.find button OK again in the last "while" in "cant_send"? My "delay" variable for button click delay, should I put it in time.sleep inside "if button" or inside "while i> = len (users)"? Thanks

Comment: P.S: what are the second and third While loops for?

Comment: I respect you and I respect your answer. I believe that the code is correct (although I'm not sure), so considering that there are a few hours left before the bounty expires, I accept your answer, but I hope you will still answer the two comments above, because I did not understand very well in what are the changes you made. I hope you will be honest too and respect my questions about your changes (even if I have already accepted the answer), maybe even inserting some comments in your code. Thanks :)

Comment: @Jas_99 The script works the same as before, I added two while loops to be sure that two conditions are satisfied. When you scoll down new users are not loaded immediately but it requires some time, from 0,1 seconds to 2 seconds or more. The purpose of `while i >= len(users)` is to wait until new users are loaded if `i` (number of users checked) is bigger or equal to `len(users)` (number of loaded users). Similarly, when you click OK in the popup, it requires some time to effectively close. The purpose of the second `while` is to wait until popup is closed. Put delay before `button[0].click()`

Comment: Are you saying that you modify your code by moving time.sleep (2) before button [0] .click ()? So time.sleep (2) right after if button?

Comment: continued comment above) I have 2 last questions please, I hope you will answer me 1.Where should I enter my delay input variable for the delay between one click and another click? Should I put it inside the time.sleep(2) we talked about above? (the one inside if button) Then replace time.sleep(2) with time.sleep (delay)? 
2. What do you mean by loading new users into the first while i> = len (users) loop?Can you explain yourself better? Are you talking about the users who are loaded gradually with the scrollbar that scrolls down? Otherwise,how are new users loaded?I do not understand. Thanks

Comment: @Jas_99 about the `time.sleep(2)`, if you click on "edited yesterday" at the bottom of the answer, you can see the edits history and compare one version with the next one. Put delay between `if button:` and `button[0].click()`. Yes, I was talking about users who are loaded gradually as you scroll down